# Как сделать вход в некоторые активти только для юзеров купивших эту возможность?

Tags: android-studio

Как сделать вход в некоторые активти только для юзеров купивших эту возможность?
В приложении есть несколько кнопок ведущих к разным активити и скажем нажать на первую и войти в первую активити может любой, но мне хочется чтобы во все остальные могли входить только юзеры купившие приложение или расширенную версию

Comment: Я бы поставлял две версии приложение - демо и полную. Соответственно в демо этих активити просто нет, а кнопки задизейблены

Comment: это как то не красиво выглядит, а нету другого способа или это слишком сложно?